# VS 2015 RTM Deploying or creating packages for 8.1 Universal app fails

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, win-universal-app

I have VS 2015 RTM on Windows 10 RTM, suddenly (maybe an update) is causing today that any project 8.1 Universal can't be deployed anymore, not emulator, not device. I have confirmed it happens with any new project or existing one.

This does not happen with 8.1 Silverlight projects! which is even more strange. I have reinstalled VS 2015 and the latest cumulative Windows Update for IE and the problem persists.

EDIT: It also happens when trying to create app packages for the project but this time crashes VS!

Have any one came into this lately? Any ideas?

UPDATE: I get - An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll
when debugging the crash when creating packages, but can't find more information

Comment: Cannot repro. What's the error you saw when deploy? Try to run "devenv -setup" on developer command line, and give mins to let the IDE recover itself in background. You can check in task manager to make sure devenv process closed before you open the VS again.

Comment: Hi Alan, there is no error just the status bar and a message box saying the deploy failed and "there were deployment errors" but can't find anything in output or error list panes. The command did not fix :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! I uninstalled the Apache Cordova tools and the problem is gone magically, don't know what conflict may these tools cause with the 8.1 SDK but sure has to be investigated.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that VS2015 hides some errors (not sure why or how). When it happens, try open VS2013 (if that is an option for you) and build there. It'll correctly tell you what the error is, and once you fix it you can return to 2015.

Comment: Hmm I would not want to install VS 2013 but I think that's the way to go right now, still this has to be fixed in 2015

Comment: Absolutely - this is not a proper solution at all. But at least it is a workaround so you can carry on working right now.